# Mysql export to csv with group total

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to export my record into csv from mysql, I want to achieve this output in generated csv:

```
Date        |   Name    |   Score
-------------------------------------
10/01/17    |   John    |   1
10/02/17    |   John    |   3
10/03/17    |   John    |   12

Total                       16
-------------------------------------
10/01/17    |   Peter   |   4
10/02/17    |   Peter   |   17
10/03/17    |   Peter   |   3

Total                       24
```

My current code is working but without the total row. See below for my current code.

```
function toCsv($data) {
    $fp = fopen('report.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

$arr = ['Data', 'Name', 'Score'];

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = [
        $row['date'],
        $row['name'],
        $row['score']
    ];

    $arr[] = $data;
}
toCsv($arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the scores to a `$total` variable while you're fetching each row.

Also, the initial value of `$arr` should be an array containing the headers as a second array.

```
function toCsv($data) {
    $fp = fopen('report.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

$arr = [['Date', 'Name', 'Score']];
$total = 0;
$last_name = null;
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($last_name && $last_name != $row['name']) {
        // Name has changed, add a total row for previous name
        $arr[] = ['Total', $total];
        $total = 0;
        $last_name = $row['name'];
    }
    $data = [
        $row['date'],
        $row['name'],
        $row['score']
    ];

    $arr[] = $data;
    $total += $row['score']
}
// Add total row for last name
$arr[] = ["Total", $total];
toCsv($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the total is always at the end of the row. I want the total will be at the end of each group

Comment: I've added code to create a total row whenever the name changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add new array containing total at the end

```
//.........
//.........
$total = 0;
$arr = ['Data', 'Name', 'Score'];
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = [
        $row['date'],
        $row['name'],
        $row['score']
    ];
    $total = $total+$row['score'];
    $arr[] = $data;
}
$total_arr = array(
    "Total",
    "-",
    $total
);
$arr[] = $total_arr;
toCsv($arr);
```